Fetch Data / Show Data SQL Server into React JS
Hello anyone can teach me about fetch data from SQL Server into ReacJS. Or you can send me documentary about this problem.i did show data from mysql and thats easy but about to show sqlserver are hard to me. Thank you for response.
Show data from SQL Server into React JS,

Please don't question which is vague, this is not specific problem and there are different ways to achieve what you're looking for. Generally, you can use API (if backend is on different language), or just utilize ORM's like Sequelize, Prisma, etc.

This question is not trivial my friend; ReactJS is a client (It's runtime is inside the web browser) and SQL Server a server (server side application). Since they are in separates worlds, they can't communicate with eachother. So you need medium that can communicate with both technologies (ReactJS and SQL Server); in other ways a web server application.
Web servers, come in various flavor and sizes but since you're using ReactJS, I guess you can code in Javascript. My advise is that you learn NodeJS and use a popular framework like ExpressJS.
There is plenty of documentation, webbinar, tutorial, etc. of NodeJS and ExpressJS online so you won't have any issue finding it.

ahh.. like html,php,sql server. php as medium communicate dude?

If PHP is the language of your preference, go ahead.
